# Password validator with 8 characters and 2 digits don't work

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords, character, digits

Hey i'm trying to make this password validator working with 8 characters and 2 digits  but.. it doesn't.
I don't see how there's something wrong about my code .My console doesn't say that there's an error

```
                    <div class="field with-indicator">
                        <label for="pass-one">Password:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="pass-one" id="pass-one" />
                        <span id="validity" class="indicator">Not Ok</span>
                    </div>

<script>
    let input = document.getElementById('pass-one');
let regex = new RegExp("^(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){1,})(?=(.*[0-9]){2,}).{8}$");

if ( !regex.test(input)) 
{
document.getElementById("validity").innerHTML = "Not Ok";
//return false;           
  } 
else 
  {
   document.getElementById("validity").innerHTML = "Ok";
   }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make your code work you need to wrap it into an event handler. For instance you may use the [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event and the [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to set the handler:

```js
document.getElementById('pass-one').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    let regex = new RegExp("^(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){1,})(?=(.*[0-9]){2,}).{8}$");

    if ( !regex.test(this.value)) {
        document.getElementById("validity").innerHTML = "Not Ok";
        //return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("validity").innerHTML = "Ok";
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="field with-indicator">
    <label for="pass-one">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="pass-one" id="pass-one" />
    <span id="validity" class="indicator">Not Ok</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make validation e.g. after each input changes `oninput="validPass()"` (I not change your regexp but add wrapper validPass() function and event in you `<input>` tag in snippet below - but if you wanna passwort to be at least 8 characters or longer then change last part in regexp `.{8}$` to `.{8,}$`)

```js
let input = document.getElementById('pass-one');
let regex = new RegExp("^(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){1,})(?=(.*[0-9]){2,}).{8}$");

function validPass() {

  if ( !regex.test(input.value)) 
  {
  document.getElementById("validity").innerHTML = "Not Ok";      
  } 
  else 
  {
   document.getElementById("validity").innerHTML = "Ok";
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="field with-indicator">
    <label for="pass-one">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="pass-one" id="pass-one" oninput="validPass()" />
    <span id="validity" class="indicator" >Not Ok</span>
</div>
```